# Moto g4 play doesn't vibrate after upgrade to Nougat 7.1

Tags: 7.1-nougat, vibration, motorola-moto-g-4g

My son's G4play phone OS was upgraded last week from marshmallow to stock Nougat 7.1. Since then vibration is not functioning at all, either for calls, notifications, or "vibrate on touch". Any fixes out there? Phone/OS is unaltered - no boot unlock, rooting etc. Standard Google play apps.